# how to implement rewarded ads in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

How to implement rewarded ad in flutter.I am trying to implement rewarded ad in flutter but getting this error.

RewardedAd failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: []))
I/hwaps   (26743): JNI_OnLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to sign the application to get the config.

You can read more in the [issue](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/307) on the [googleads-mobile-flutter](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter) library's  githab .